# When developing Chrome extension, Chrome React Devtools doesn't show up

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I am debugging my chrome extension pop page, and open it in uri :
 chrome-extension://keekhfjbmbpmlgpfljclblgbjchoencn/popup.html

This page is using reactjs, but the react devtools is not showing.
Is it by design?

Comment: Pretty sure chrome extensions cannot operate on the pages of other extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use React Dev Tools but you will have to use the [standalone version](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools) to work in browser extension (because of CSP restrictions). Run this in your console

```
$ npm install -g react-devtools
```

and add this to you manifest.json

```
"content_security_policy": "connect-src ws://localhost:8097"
```

Now run `react-devtools`
Don't forget to reload your extension.

P.S.
If you don't want to install `react-devtools` globally you can run `npm install --save-dev react-devtools` from your project and then add to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "react-devtools": "react-devtools"
}
```

And run `npm run react-devtools`

Comment: The devtools still display `Waiting for React to connect...`. It seems like you have to load its script in the extension somehow, but adding it to the beginning of `content_scripts[*].js` errors with `Could not load javascript '' for content script.` when installing with Chrome.

Comment: Looks like you have another problem. Please ask a new question with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I got it to work by importing `react-devtools` directly. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools#usage-with-react-dom

Comment: How does that approach look like for extensions which use manifest v3?

Answer (score 2):

The React Dev Tools needs to inject a content script in your page to check your react components. To do that they declare in their manifest the pattern  that matches any url with a permitted scheme and these are (from the docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns):

http, https, file, ftp

In other words: the React Developer Tools can not run in extension pages.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to make it work with manifest v3:

- installed it locally: `npm i -D react-devtools`
- added `"react-devtools": "react-devtools"` to `package.json` scripts
- imported the package at the top of the file that calls `render`: `import 'react-devtools'`
- and the final step was to open Devtools with `npm run react-devtools`